# Misunderstanding of Python imports

Tags: python, import

I am having a recurring problem in the way I program and I need help restructuring the way I do things.

**Warning: This is a long question. I want to include as much information about the nature of the error as possible to exhaust possible causes of it.**

**TL;DR Version:** `import`/`include` order isn't letting my main file see functions defined in other files. How can I improve my programming style to prevent this later?

**Long version:** I'll use Python 2.7 as an example. Let's say I have a file, `main.py`, and another file, `foo.py`. `main.py` has all my main code, and `foo.py` has a class that contains data used in `main.py`. What I do is I define the class's object in that same file, `foo.py`, right after the class definition. I figure if I just instantiate the class there, I can simply import that file into any other files that need it, and the object will already exist to be used immediately. No mucking about with instantiating the class at some point and worrying whether or not something before the class's instantiation needs it before it's actually defined.

The problem is that this normally works, until I do that with another class defined in another file. The interpreter can't find the object of the second class, even if I import it once in `main.py` (therefore this does not seem to be an issue of duplicate objects stemming from multiple imports). So, in essence, `main.py` can see `foo.py`'s class object, but not, say, `bar.py`'s object.

I normally set up a project so that I have one main file, and other files that define data and the uses and handling for that data. The main file calls one function or method that gets the ball rolling by calling other functions and methods throughout the program. I import just the data for the class whose method I'm calling, and in the file that has the data used in the main file, I import all the other stuff that particular file needs. This seems logical to me if I'm to make a memory-efficient program, but there is obviously something wrong with the way I'm doing things, because it never seems to work with bigger programs.

Here is a simple example in code of (a. how I set up my file hierarchies, (b. how I set up my imports, and (c. an example of the types of errors I get:

main.py:

```
import foo
import bar

print foo.bar
print bat.bar
```

foo.py:

```
class Foo:
  def __init__(self):
    bar = 5

foo = Foo()
```

bar.py:

```
class Bar:
  def __init__(self):
    bar = "Hello"

bat = Bar()
```

And here's the error I get when I run this program:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\main.py", line 4, in <module>
    print foo.bar
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'bar'
```

When I change main.py to this:

```
from foo import *
from bar import *

print foo.bar
print bat.bar
```

it gets a different error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\main.py", line 4, in <module>
    print foo.bar
AttributeError: Foo instance has no attribute 'bar'
```

Am I misunderstanding how to use imports or what? Because if I step back and make `main.py` like this:

```
from foo import *
from bar import *

foo = Foo()
bat = Bar()

print foo.bar
print bat.bar
```

while commenting out the instantiation of the classes in the other files, I get the same error: `Foo instance has no attribute 'bar'`.

Why is this?

This doesn't just happen with Python, it happens to me with C++ too, so this is why I suggest it may be my programming style that is an issue here and not so much anything syntactical.

Comment: This is likely to be too broad of a question, so I don't think it is a good question for the site. Additionally, you don't seem to have a strong grasp on Python basics, like class attributes; I would suggest going through a decent Python tutorial to get the basics in place.

Comment: In your classes you must use p.e. `self.bar = 5` instead of `bar = 5` in this way you will be able to call bar property from the instance

Answer (score 3):

`import X` creates an `X` object in your current namespace which contains the names defined in that module. This only ever adds a *single* name to your namespace. So, in your first example,

```
import foo
import bar
```

makes `foo` a module object containing the class `Foo` (accessible as `foo.Foo`) and the object `foo` (accessible as `foo.foo`); similarly, `bar` has the class `bar.Bar` and the object `bar.bat`. Notably, because there's no variable called `bar` in the top-level of the module `foo`, `foo.bar` doesn't exist.

`from X import Y` imports everything matching `Y` from the module `X` directly into your namespace. This might create a bunch of names in your current namespace. So,

```
from foo import *
```

creates both the names `Foo` (referring to a class) and `foo` (referring to an instance of `Foo`). So, in the latter case, `foo` will refer to an instance of the class `Foo`, so why doesn't `foo.bar` work?

Well, you didn't actually define `foo.bar`. The code

```
def __init__(self):
    bar = 5
```

defines a **local variable** called `bar` with value `5`. It doesn't save anything to the class instance! You'd have to write

```
def __init__(self):
    self.bar = 5
```

to have this work at all.

If you're having similar issues with C++, I'd suggest slowing down and just focusing on one language at a time. There's no good reason to try learning both simultaneously, as it'll just confuse you in the long term. Get a solid understanding of one language (I'd personally recommend Python) before trying to learn the other.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I was thinking it was something with the classes, but I've made classes like that before and had them work. Like this one: http://pastebin.com/VuZ0yViZ

What am I doing in this that it works and the above does not? Because I'm basically setting up the classes in the same way as my example

Comment: You are saying "_It doesn't save anything to the class! You'd have to write (...)_", but then you write example on how to set an attribute of _an instance_, not _a class_. That is just minor thing, upvoting anyway.

Comment: Can you explain that more, Tadeck? I think that's hitting the core of it

Comment: Okay I think I got it. I made a program like this: class Ex():
  ack = None
  def __init__(self):
    ack = 2
e = Ex()
print e.ack
input()